# Recent Activities Web Part on MySite causes null object error

Tags: 2013, web-part, mysites

Whenever a user is on their MySite and goes to their blog and tries adding a Recent Activities web part to the page, the page comes back saying:

```
The "PublishedNewsFeedWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The ULS is equally unhelpful:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.t Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.PublishedNewsFeedWebPart.RenderWebPart(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPart
Pages.WebPart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPChro
me.RenderPartContents(HtmlTextWriter output, WebPart part)
```

I found [this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/27/what-features-are-removeddepreciated-from-sharepoint-2013/) site that says the Recent Activities web part is deprecated.  Is this true?  Does anyone else's Recent Activities web part work in 2013?